# Swift animation completion bug with release build settings

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

There are two view controllers, Initial and modal. We have animation in the initial controller and also animation in the modal controller. Each animation have completion block. We set build scheme Run –> Build configuration to Release. Run app, go to modal controller and run the animation. After animation (in the modal controller) the completion block of animation in the Initial controller is invoked instead of the completion block in Modal controller. Is anybody also experiencing with that? Any suggestions?

[Sample project here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m1iu2wlqjswvcwh/AnimationCompletionBug.zip?dl=0)
(Product -> Scheme -> Edit scheme -> Run -> Build configuration: Release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely a optimizations bug.

A quick workaround I found is casting `completions:` closures as `@objc_block`.

ViewController:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
        delay: 0.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: { () -> Void in
            self.rectangleView.alpha = 1.0
        },
        completion: { (complete) -> Void in
            println("111 Hello ViewController 1")
        } as @objc_block (Bool) -> Void
        //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    )
```

ViewController2:

```
    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration,
        delay: 0.0,
        options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeLinear,
        animations: { () -> Void in
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime( 0.0,
                relativeDuration: (duration / 2),
                animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.rectangleView.alpha = 0.1
                }
            )
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(
                (duration / 2),
                relativeDuration: (duration / 2),
                animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.rectangleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                }
            )
        },
        completion: { (complete) -> Void in
            println("Hello ViewController 2")
        } as @objc_block (Bool) -> Void
        //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    )
```